# How to exclude associations build with model.associated.build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently upgrading an existing application from rails 3 to 4. I've encountered changed behaviour, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

say the following exists;

```
class Program
  has_many :pauses
end

class Pause
  belongs_to :program

  def dates
    (starts_at...ends_at)
  end

  validate :validate_without_overlap

  def validate_without_overlap
    return if (program.pauses.map(&:dates).flatten & [starts_at, ends_at]).blank?
    # set errors...
  end
end

program = Program.create 
program.pauses.build starts_at: 1.week.ago.to_date, ends_at: Date.today

# ...

program.save
```

To verify the pause does not have a overlap with existing pauses, within a 
validation method the following happens:

```
program.pauses.map(&:dates)
```

This already includes the builded pause record. Which triggers a validation error because it overlaps itself. How to kill groundhog day?

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude new records use something like this:

```
program.pauses.select { |o| !o.new_record? }.map(&:dates)
```

or

```
program.pauses.reject(&:new_record?).map(&:dates)
```